# I want to know (with examples!) if there is a way to search through a list (not a file) and if it's found replace it

Tags: java

I want to know (with examples!) if there is a way to search through a list (not a file) and if it's found replace it.

Background: Making a server but I want it to censor swear words and the system i have works it's just not efficient enough.

Current Code:

```
     String impmessage = message.replaceAll("swearword1", "f***");
     String impmessage2 = impmessage.replaceAll("swearword2", "bi***");
     String impmessage3 = impmessage2.replaceAll("swearword3", "b***");
     String impmessage4 = impmessage3.replaceAll("swearword4", "w***");
     ...
     String impmessage8 = impmessage7.replace('%', '&');
```

The whole shabang. But when I want to add a new word into the filter I have to add another one on there.

Comment: Just to ensure, that I getting it right. You are asking for help? 'I want to know (with examples!)' sounds so unpolite.

Comment: 10 downvotes in a minute, i think that's a new record

Comment: Google 'clbuttic'.  And for the record, even though I personally don't care about the profanity, but it is certainly against the faq ( http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette ).

Comment: Thank you @iccthedral for making the example more appropriate for the site.

Comment: +1 for @iccthedral not for OP.

Comment: the approach you are taking won't work. What about using `@` for `a` or `5` for `s`. Or putting `-` or `.` between the letters of the words. I have implemented such as system, this is a naive solution that will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic solution is below:

```
Map<String, String> mapping = new HashMap();
mapping.put("frak","f***");

String censoredMsg = message;
for (String word : mapping.KeySet()) {
  censoredMsg = censoredMsg.replaceAll(word, mapping.get(word));
}
```

How you create the mapping is somewhat up to you. Here is another more comprehensive solution including pulling in from a random file:

```
public class TheMan {
  private Set<String> uglyWords;

  public TheMan() {
    getBlacklist();
  }

  private void getBlacklist() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("wordsidontlike.txt"));
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
      String word = scanner.nextLine();
      uglyWords.add(word);
    }
  }

  public String censorMessage(String message) {
    String censoredMsg = message;
    for (String word : uglyWords) {
      String replacement = word.charAt(0);
      StringUtils.rightPad(replacement, word.length(), '*');
      censoredMsg = censoredMsg.replaceAll(word, replacement);
    }
    return censoredMsg;
  }
}
```

Comment: That should be `censoredMsg = censoredMsg.replaceAll`, both times.